# Testing whether numbers are relatively prime

Tags: python, beginner

```
import math

OK = True
test = 1
openFile = open("numbers", "r")
sir = []
for val in openFile.read().split():
    sir.append(int(val))
    test += 1
    if test > 2:
        if math.gcd(sir[test-3], sir[test-2]) > 1:
            OK = False
openFile.close()
print(OK)
```

This program need to print True, if the GCD of all numbers in that sequence is 1, false if it isn't. Is there an efficient way to make the code shorter?

Comment: The program only checks that the `gcd` of consecutive pairs is 1. Not exactly what the problem statement asks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the bottom you will find a more Pythonic version of your code, with all of its bugs still intact. The changes made include:

#### Use a context manager for files

This construct:

```
with open("file1", "r") as f:
```

allows the removal of `f.close()` and is just generally more robust.

#### Lists know how long they are

I removed the unneeded `test` variable and simply use something like `sir[-x]` to reference elements from the end of the list.  This allows changing:

```
gcd(sir[test-3], sir[test-2])
```

to the equivalent:

```
gcd(*sir[-2:])
```

This also removes the off by one error in `test`.  So I guess this review did fix a bug.

#### Break from loop as soon as possible

Once you have your answer, there is no point in continuing a loop.

#### Restructure to lower number of tests needed

By starting the loop with `sir=[1]` instead of an empty list, the list is long enough to test for `gcd` in the first loop, and thus a length check is not needed.

#### Full Listing

```
import math

OK = True
sir = [1]
with open("file1", "r") as f:
    for val in f.read().split():
        sir.append(int(val))
        if math.gcd(*sir[-2:]) > 1:
            OK = False
            break
print(OK, sir)
```